# Unable to send a mail using perl Mime::Lite

Tags: perl

I am unable to send a mail using MIME::Lite. While sending from my desktop it will through the below errors.
Error: "SMTP Failed to connect to mail server: Bad file descriptor"

I am using the below mentioned code.

```
use strict;
use MIME::Lite;
use Net::SMTP;

my $from_address = "no-reply@host.com";
my $to_address = "madhan@host.com";
my $cc_address = "madhan@host.com";
my $subject = "Test mail";
my $message_body = "Madhan test mail";
my $namer="madhankumar";
my $regards="Madhan M";

print " Sending mail from $from_address to $to_address \n";
my $person_name=ucfirst($namer).",";
my $mail_host = 'mail1.somehost.com';


my $msg = MIME::Lite->new (
  From => $from_address,
  To => $to_address,
  Cc => $cc_address,
  Subject => $subject,
  Type =>'multipart/mixed'
) or die "Error creating multipart container: $!\n";

$msg->attach (
  Type => 'TEXT',
  Data => "Dear $person_name\n\n".$message_body."\n\nRegards,\n$regards"
) or die "Error adding the text message part: $!\n";

MIME::Lite->send('smtp', $mail_host, Timeout=>60);
  $msg->send;
```

The above code is working fine while the mail server is connected with LAN. While using the code in remote system the error has been thrown as mentioned in below

```
"SMTP Failed to connect to mail server: Bad file descriptor".
```

May I know the reason.. Is the code run in remote system. If not what are the change I have made the code.. Please share your solutions....

Thanks in advance...

Note: I am developing this in Windows XP

Comment: Since it is only working in your LAN are you sure that `$mail_host` is reachable from both? Can you ping it? Can you connect to port 25?

Comment: In LAN the host is pinging. I didn't check in remote system. How can i set port? Am i need to set Incoming port and Outgoing port while run the code in remote? If yes please guide me how to proceed for the same

Comment: SMTP uses port 25. This means that you have to be able to reach port 25 on the smtp server. You should check your firewall settings.

Comment: The error is from `Net::SMTP` and has nothing with `MIME::Lite` to do.

Comment: Ok Tripleee... What is the way to resolve these kind of errors....?

Comment: Read and understand what @Matteo wrote. If you cannot connect to the mail server, either the host name is invalid, or your port 25 access is blocked. This is a fairly common measure by ISPs these days to contain spam and malware bots.  If you have legit needs, ask them how to bypass the block. One common solution is to use authenticated SMTP.

Answer (score 6):

The variables do not contain what you think they contain. If you had switched on warnings, you would have noticed this on your own.

```
$ perl -e'use warnings; my $from_address = "no-reply@host.com";'
Possible unintended interpolation of @host in string at -e line 1.
Name "main::host" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
```

The remedy is to use single quotes to delimit those strings.