# How can I send mail in a Perl script?

Tags: perl

I have adapted a script from the Perl Cookbook. I am testing it to send mail to myself in gmail.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use MIME::Lite;
my $msg;
    $msg = MIME::Lite->new(From => 'zmumba@gmail.com',
    To => 'zmumba@gmail.com',
    Subject => 'My office photo',
    Type => 'multipart/mixed');

 $msg->attach(Type => 'image/png',
         Path => '/home/zmumba/ZMD_Proj/Docs/Reporting',
         Filename => 'office_lyout.png');

$msg->attach(Type => 'TEXT',
         Data => 'I hope you can use this!');

  $msg->send( );
```

When I run this script, I get the message "/home/zmumba/ZMD_Proj/Docs/Reporting" not readable.
From here [How can I send mail through Gmail with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279757/how-can-i-send-mail-through-gmail-with-perl) , I now understand that I have to send mail through a mailserver to use MIME::Lite. So I replaced

```
$msg = MIME::Lite->new(From => 'zmumba@gmail.com
```

with

```
$msg = Email::Send::Gmail->new(From => 'zmumba@gmail.com
```

and I get the error "Can't locate object method "new" via package Email::Send::Gmail".

Then I tried

```
    $msg = Net::IMAP::Simple::SSL->new(From => 'zmumba@gmail.com',
```

and I get "Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /home/zmumba/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 25.
Can't call method "attach" on an undefined value at ...".
Any assistance on how to go about it?
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: I deleted the link. Please don't link to pirated books! (I note that it was also a book for Perl 4. It is **horribly** out of date and far FAR away from best practise)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to send a mail using perl Mime::Lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084715/unable-to-send-a-mail-using-perl-mimelite)

Comment: @Quentin Despite that URL, the Perl Cookbook is perl5. Still horribly outdated since it's from 2003 though.

Comment: Take a look at the [recently updated perlfaq entry](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfaq9#How-do-I-send-email?) on this topic.

Comment: I've used core [Net::SMTP](https://perldoc.perl.org/Net/SMTP.html), and directly `sendmail` (with `-oi -t`) and both have been fine (where the second one is limited to machines with `sendmail`)

Comment: Sorry, but this looks like fiddling around without any kind of understanding what you are doing and  especially without reading documentation - therefore downvoted. It isn't even possible to send email with IMAP in the first place since IMAP protocol is just for reading mails.

Answer (score 2):

The Perl Cookbook is 20 years old and its recommendations will be out of date.  [Using MIME::Lite is discouraged](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite#WAIT!).

> MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer. There are a number of alternatives, like Email::MIME or MIME::Entity and Email::Sender, which you should probably use instead. MIME::Lite continues to accrue weird bug reports, and it is not receiving a large amount of refactoring due to the availability of better alternatives. Please consider using something else.

You should probably follow their recommendation and use [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender).

---

> *"Can't locate object method "new" via package Email::Send::Gmail"*

You need to load Email::Send::Gmail with `use Email::Send::Gmail`.

You may need to install the [Email::Send::Gmail](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Send::Gmail) module. It's simplest to do this using either [cpanminus](https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus/tree/devel/App-cpanminus) or [install a fresh Perl with perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) and then use cpanminus.

---

> Then I tried
>
> ```
> $msg = Net::IMAP::Simple::SSL->new(From => 'zmumba@gmail.com',
> ```
>
> and I get "Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /home/zmumba/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/IMAP/Simple.pm line 25.

MIME::Lite, Email::Send::Gmail, and [Net::IMAP::Simple::SSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IMAP::Simple::SSL) are different libraries with different interfaces that take different arguments differently. Refer to their documentation for how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before, both MIME::Lite and Email::Send is discouraged -

> Email::Send is going away... well, not really going away, but it's
>   being officially marked "out of favor." It has API design problems
>   that make it hard to usefully extend and rather than try to deprecate
>   features and slowly ease in a new interface, we've released
>   Email::Sender which fixes these problems and others

I have created a script which uses Email::MIME, Email::Sender::Simple, Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP for sending mail. You can take a look at https://github.com/rai-gaurav/perl-toolkit/tree/master/Mail and use it as per your requirement.
Important lines from that code are -

```
sub create_mail {
    my ( $self, $file_attachments, $mail_subject, $mail_body ) = @_;

    my @mail_attachments;
    if (@$file_attachments) {
        foreach my $attachment (@$file_attachments) {
            my $single_attachment = Email::MIME->create(
                attributes => {
                    filename     => basename($attachment),
                    content_type => "application/json",
                    disposition  => 'attachment',
                    encoding     => 'base64',
                    name         => basename($attachment)
                },
                body => io->file($attachment)->all
            );
            push( @mail_attachments, $single_attachment );
        }
    }
    # Multipart message : It contains attachment as well as html body
    my @parts = (
        @mail_attachments,
        Email::MIME->create(
            attributes => {
                content_type => 'text/html',
                encoding     => 'quoted-printable',
                charset      => 'US-ASCII'
            },
            body_str => $mail_body,
        ),
    );

    my $mail_to_users    = join ', ', @{ $self->{config}->{mail_to} };
    my $cc_mail_to_users = join ', ', @{ $self->{config}->{mail_cc_to} };

    my $email = Email::MIME->create(
        header => [
            From    => $self->{config}->{mail_from},
            To      => $mail_to_users,
            Cc      => $cc_mail_to_users,
            Subject => $mail_subject,
        ],
        parts => [@parts],
    );
    return $email;
}

sub send_mail {
    my ( $self, $email ) = @_;
    my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new(
        {
            host => $self->{config}->{smtp_server}
        }
    );
    eval { sendmail( $email, { transport => $transport } ); };
    if ($@) {
        return 0, $@;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gmail and other mail servers will not allow unauthorized relay. In most cases you will need authorized access.

Here is what I use, after also trying many modules. Maybe this solution seems a little bit overdone, but it's easy to change for HTML with plain text as alternative or other attachments. Parameters of the transport are the most common ones.

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail try_to_sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS;
use Email::Simple ();
use Email::Simple::Creator ();
use Email::MIME;

send_my_mail('john.doe@hisdomain.com','Test','Test, pls ignore');

sub send_my_mail {
  my ($to_mail_address, $subject, $body_text) = @_;

  my $smtpserver   = 'smtp.mydomain.com';
  my $smtpport     = 587;
  my $smtpuser     = 'me@mydomain.com';
  my $smtppassword = 'mysecret';

  my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS->new({
    host          => $smtpserver,
    ssl           => 'starttls',
    port          => $smtpport,
    sasl_username => $smtpuser,
    sasl_password => $smtppassword,
    #debug => 1,
  });

  my $text_part = Email::MIME->create(
    attributes => {
        'encoding'     => 'quoted-printable',
        'content_type' => 'text/plain',
        'charset'      => 'UTF-8',
    },
    'body_str' => $body_text,
  );

  my $alternative_part = Email::MIME->create(
    attributes => {
        'content_type' => 'multipart/alternative',
    },
    parts => [ $text_part, ],
  );

  my $email = Email::MIME->create(
    header_str => [
        To      => $to_mail_address,
        From    => "Website <$smtpuser>",
        Subject => $subject,
    ],
    attributes => {
             'content_type' => 'multipart/mixed',
         },
    parts => [  $alternative_part   ],
  );

  my $status = try_to_sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });

  return $status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Email::Send::Gmail](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Send::Gmail) module. It might solve your problem.